# In JPA mapping class to primitive

Tags: java, jpa

I want to mapping a class to a primitive type

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PERSON")
public class Person implements Serializable {
    ...
   private Email email = null;
    ...
   @Column(name="email")
   public Email getEmail() {
      return email;
   }
   public void setEmail(Email email) {
      this.email=email;
   }
}
```

In this example I want to save the email like a String

I wish something like:

```
interface someInterface{

   String getValue();
   void setValue(String p);

}
```

Then if I implement this interface in Email it can be save and loaded transparently (I haven't find something like this).

I don't want to serialize the class

I use Email as a example, but I have in mind many other class, to little to be a whole entity.

Any idea?

Comment: There is some confusing aspects here, like the "primitive type". But are you looking for something like `@Embeddable` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JPA2.1 provides AttributeConverter which means that a field can be marked with a converter persisting it as, for example, a String. All JPA implementations have their own variant currently, but [DataNucleus JPA](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_1) provides the JPA2.1 feature already, see the foot of [this page](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_1/jpa/types.html).

Answer (score 0):

Make two variables. Email which is object and that you mark as @Transient and emailStr that you store in the database. The emailStr getter and setter should be private, and the getEmail creates the email object (lazily) based on the emailStr.

Another solution, if you have email in many entities is to create a custom UserType.

Just google hibernate UserType..

Answer (score 0):

You can use converters in EclipseLink for this,

see,
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Mapping/Basic_Mappings/Default_Conversions_and_Converters

Comment: I think is exactly what I want, but I can't find code examples.In this [example](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Mapping/Basic_Mappings/Default_Conversions_and_Converters/Converter) do you know where I can find _GenderConverter_?

Comment: The Converter interface is pretty simple,  http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.3/org/eclipse/persistence/mappings/converters/Converter.html , I did not find a gneder converter in our examples, but did find a CustomSexConverter in our tests, http://dev.eclipse.org/svnroot/rt/org.eclipse.persistence/trunk/jpa/eclipselink.jpa.test/src/org/eclipse/persistence/testing/models/jpa/advanced/CustomSexConverter.java

Answer (score -1):

There's nothing stopping you from using String in your Classes as far as JPA is concerned. Or any other primitive type for that matter...

EDIT: You mean something like this hopefully

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PERSON")
public class Person implements Serializable {
    ...
   private String email = null;
    ...
   @Column(name="email")
   public String getEmail() {
      return email;
   }
   public void setEmail(String email) {
      this.email=email;
   }
}
```

Comment: I want to map Email to a String. Save him like a String

Comment: I'm not clear about your problem, so why not just put String email in your class? instead of Email email?

Comment: I prefer Email. I can ask specific think to a Email. getUser() sendMail(), etc.  I want to extract a email from the database and use it like a email :P. But save it like a primitive string.

Comment: You want to save the entire email class in a single String?